# mysql query not showing results

Tags: php, mysql

Newish to mysql. I have a query and it is not showing the value of the cell just the row name:

```
$sql="SELECT 'first' from `users` WHERE `id`= $userid ";
$res=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 

echo $row['first'] ;
```

What am I doing wrong????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove quotes from 'first' - it is a column so don't put it in quotes, you can use ` istead.
Next loop through results and that's all.

```
$sql="SELECT first from `users` WHERE `id`= $userid ";
$res=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
  echo $row['first'] ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Brackets in your query is wrong:

```
$sql = "SELECT 'first' from `users` WHERE `id` = $userid";
```

Must be:

```
$sql = "SELECT `first` from `users` WHERE `id` = $userid";
```

Note difference in `first`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo $row[0]['first'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'first'
```

will simply return the string first.

remove the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

> $sql="SELECT 'first' from `users` WHERE `id`= $userid ";

you are using normal quotes to select instead of backticks you are not selecting anything from the database.

use 
$sql="SELECT `first` from `users` WHERE `id`= $userid ";
instead

and side note:
never "be sure" that your query returns exactly 1 row

use mysql_fetch_assoc() in a loop and check if you really retrieve 1 result.